# Can I shoot any approach at an uncontrolled airport in VMC without any clearance?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

I am in IFR Flight plan to an uncontrolled airport. I find out that the weather is well above VFR limit, and hence canceled IFR flight plan. But I want to shoot an approach (with safety pilot) for my currency. In this case, can I still shoot any approach to the uncontrolled airport in VMC without any clearance?

Comment: These are two different questions.

Comment: For the first, your destination airport is above VFR, so you are planning to do an approach on the *same* airport as VFR after cancelling the flight plan, or a different airport?

Comment: Which country/regulations are you asking about? If you're asking about the US, your first question is answered [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27229/62); your second one is answered [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26958/62).

Comment: Most (all?) of your posts you don't reply to the *where* question, please do.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to cancel your IFR flight plan with ATC, fly the duration of the flight and the approach by VFR, but, yes, you could.

Many people fly practice approaches at untowered airports by announcing their intentions over the CTAF.  This can be difficult to do at beehive airports with a lot of GA traffic going into and out of them, but it’s possible.  I’ve done it plenty of time without incident.

Answer (score 0):

Flying VFR, of course. I would advise against it at a busy uncontrolled field though.